Taiwan (low speed) rail: Easycard vs. long distance local trains
Let's say I use an Easycard (saves 10%) to take the (low speed) railroad
from Fengyuan to Taipei. If I just take slower local trains to save
money, when I check out of the system in Taipei, will the computer think
I took the express trains and charge me more anyway? Isn't it supposed
to know that I took so long to arrive, so I must have been on the slower
train?

Short answer: The system determines whether you have taken an express (Tze-Chiang) train mainly by matching the time you exit the station with the train arrival times. It operates on a best-effort basis, which might yield false positives (requiring one's effort to correct the fare at a staffed counter) and false negatives (opening to customer abuse).
In some cases, the system knows (for sure) that one has taken an express train if a conductor/guard scans their card during a ticket inspection.
It is worth noting that Taiwan Railway is discontinuing its "10% off smartcard on local train fares" offer from 2024-08-19 in favour of monthly rebates and electronic season tickets. While there is no longer any financial incentive for occasional travellers to use a smartcard, the answer is still relevant to commuters due to the rebate.

Long answer:
There seem to be no official documents from Taiwan Railway on the exact procedures an exit gate takes to deduce whether one has taken an express or local train.
That said, from various local forums and news outlets, it appears the exit gate will charge one based on what trains are arriving at the station around the time when they touch out. An ex-Taiwan Railway employee said the following (translation mine):

車站的讀卡機會根據不同的列車進站時間而會扣不同的費率
比方說在某時段只有自強號進站，你在那個時間點出站，
系統就會判定你是搭那班自強號，而扣自強的費率，
所以偶爾會有出錯的情形，自己要注意是否有扣對金額。
(剛從台鐵離職)
The stations' card readers charge a different rate based on train arrival times.
For example, if you exit a station during the period when only Tze-Chiang limited express trains call, the system will determine you have taken a Tze-Chiang limited express train and charge accordingly.
As a result, the system could get it wrong occasionally -- you should check whether it has deducted the right amount.
(I just left my role at Taiwan Railway)

The matching is done on a best-effort basis, with the logic favouring customers if it cannot conclusively determine whether they have taken an express or local train. One quoted a conductor/guard when discussing whether one should comply with the request to pay up the excess fare on the train in cash (translation mine):

旅客質疑車站出口閘門不是會依據到站之車種設定好?
雖然該列車長已說明如果短時間內多種車種到站時
車站出口閘門就會設定最低階車種
但該民旅客就是堅持不補
The passenger questions, "Aren't the exit gates configured to charge based on the (speed) class of the train that has just arrived?"
Although the conductor/guard has explained that the gates are configured to charge the fare of the lowest train (speed) class present if multiple express/local trains arrive at the station within a short period [and hence, the excess fare is due on the express train], the passenger insisted not to pay the excess fare.

(Note the post was made in 2015, before Taiwan Railway updated the system to enable one using a smartcard to take express trains (sans those with mandatory reservations) without paying any excess fares on the train and, thus, might be outdated.)
In addition, the system knows you have taken an express train if the conductor/guard scanned your smartcard during an on-train ticket inspection.
A recent review of the latest Taiwan Railway ticketing system noted (translation mine):

新一代掌上型補票系統[..]亦增加了電子票證註記功能，經查驗票註記搭乘車種後，依電子票證搭乘規定扣收實際票價。
The new handheld excess fare terminals also feature the ability to mark smartcards. The smartcards are marked with the train (speed) class one has taken during ticket inspection, which enables one to charge the corresponding fare according to the smartcard T&Cs.

In practice, ticket inspections do not happen systematically for all express trains. This leads to some devising creative ways to trick the exit gates into thinking they are travelling on a local train (hence qualify for a lower fare). In the words of a news article:

不過台鐵發現，有民眾為了省錢會故意延遲出站或是中途換比較便宜的車種來逃票。
However, Taiwan Railway has identified cases of fare evasion where customers delay exiting the station or change to a slower train mid-way [the rules dictate that the express train rate applies to the entire journey, but not the portion when one takes an express train] to save money.

